Error while storing session to MySQL database
I am creating webpage using NodeJS and Express. My session works when it is stored in memory but I have problems when I try to store it in database. Every page I navigate, I get this error:
TypeError: this.connection.query is not a function
    at C:\Users\#\OneDrive\Desktop\GSWNodeJs\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:384:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at MySQLStore.query (C:\Users\#\OneDrive\Desktop\GSWNodeJs\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:381:10)
    at C:\Users\#\OneDrive\Desktop\GSWNodeJs\node_modules\express-mysql-session\index.js:170:16

If someone know if this way of connecting existing database is correct?
Here are my GET and POST methods:
exports.getLogin = (req,res,next) => {
    res.render('login', {
        path: '/login',
        pageTitle: 'Login',
    })
}
exports.postLogin = (req,res,next) => {
    req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
    res.redirect('/');
}

I have also connected database:
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('shop', 'root', 'metal', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost',
  logging: false
});
module.exports = sequelize;

Here is the part of app.js file related to session:
const session = require('express-session');
const SequelizeStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const sequelize = require('./util/database');
const options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'metal',
    database: 'shop'
};

const connection = mysql.createConnection(options);
const sessionStore = new SequelizeStore({db: sequelize}, connection);

app.use(session({
   secret: 'my secret', 
   resave:false, 
   saveUninitialized: false, 
   store: sessionStore
  }));

I expected to see sessions table in my database but I get error.

i don't think express-mysql-session supports Sequelize
